# openssl 1.0.1 and connecting to Ec2 webapplication on 8443 using curl

Tags: curl, https, amazon-ec2, openssl

From a machine with openssl 0.9.8k and curl 7.19, I can succesfully make an https connection to an EC2 webapplication on 8443.

The same curl command on a machine with openssl 1.0.1 and curl 7.22 initially fails with the obscure  SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error.  This I can fix by addnig -sslv3 to the curl command, which then results in a 401 Unauthorized error.

Why is this same command acting differently with different curl/openssl versions?  Other potentially helpful info is I'm using the -k option in both cases.

Assuming this is a low-level openssl bug not easily resolved, what is the easiest way to roll back the version on ubuntu?  Or would it be easier to just install the appropraite curl/openssl pacakages that I want, but how can I ensure when package installing the old curl version that it links to the older ssl version?

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

Since curl and openssl are open source packages, why not just compile from source?  http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html list how to specify which TLS library gets used.

Secondly, I think **the problem is actually server-side**.  That is, in response to the ClientHello, the server returns the error message.  The problem isn't with the newer client, but in how the (buggy) server responds to a message from a newer client (this isn't super uncommon -- see http://www6.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/tls/current/msg07281.html  and note that openssl 1.0.1 added support for TLS 1.1 and 1.2).  While this can be "fixed" by rolling the client back to SSLv3, the right solution is to fix the server-side of the equation.

What software is running the server side of this?  Can you upgrade that instead?

Comment: Server is running jboss, so I can look into that.  Does your answer explain why the client sslv3 fix (through curl flag) fails though?

Comment: It does not explain the 401 response.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby to the Rescue!  While I still cannot get it still does not work via the -sslv3 flag with CURL, [this post](http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/05/tls-error-with-ruby-client-and-tomcat-server/) saved the day.  The catch is the http.ssl_version method is not in the ruby 1.8 net/https, hence why I missed it before, I had to upgrade to ruby 1.9.2, but this seesm to do the trick, curl still fails with the 401 error, but that's not really a concern now, since ruby works